# TIMESTAMP error importing database tables from Mysql 5.6.30 to Mysql 5.1.73

Tags: import, export, mysql

﻿﻿When doing a MYSQLDUMP of a database (Magento 2.0) and attempting to import it into another server, I get this error:

```
[ERROR in query 13] Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

the source server is Mysql 5.6.30 and the target server runs Mysql 5.1.73.

Is there any workaround?  I'm thinking:

- I can tell `mysqldump` to export the data structure compatible with the previous version (that would be ideal)
- I will have to add some flag on the import side (currently those tables are not being imported)
- I will just have to rewrite the TIMESTAMPS to datetime fields (not optimal)

Thank you

Comment: You don't have to change the types of the fields, just get rid of the `DEFAULT` or `ON UPDATE` operations.

Comment: `As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table.`. See [11.3.5 Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).